# Closest match for two variables

Tags: microsoft-excel

Need to be able to enter 2 (and eventually more) variables and find the record (date) that most closely matches BOTH.

Here are my variables:

[image: variables]

Here is a sample of my records:

[image: records]

To clarify, I don't want the closest match for '3 mo chg' to be from one date and 'Avg Vol 3m' from another. I need ONE date record that best matches BOTH variables. I realize there will probably be some subjectivity in what qualifies as the "best" match. That's fine, just looking for some ideas.

What's the best method to achieve this?

Comment: I've tried dividing each record by my input variables and then summing - looking for the sum that was closest to '2.00' But, this doesn't work, because the result for 'Avg Vol 3m' might be 5.00 and the result for '3 mo chg' might be -3.00. The sum is 2.00, but this record would not be a good match.

Comment: You have to define best match. In statistics, it would be fitting a curve to the data, then measuring the various distance of the various data points from the curve. The best match would be the data point "nearest" your search criteria.

Comment: For example, if it was determined a straight line was the best representation of the data, then 1) compute the regression line. 2) for each data point calculate (in a new column) the distance of the data point from the line (I believe it is a sum of squares calculation). 3) compute the distance of your search criteria. 4) compare the search criteria distance from the list of distances. The closest one is your result.

I leave it up to you to actually convert my suggestion into excel formulas.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the row with the minimum total deviation from your specified values.  A formula similar to this one will do that.

```
=ABS((E2-B$1)/B$1)+ABS((F2-B$2)/B$2)
```

This calculates the percent deviation from each value, takes the absolute value, and adds them together.  The table below shows a "helper" column with the total deviation.  The closest match is the row where the deviation is smallest.

[image]

A formula in Conditional Formatting `=IF(G2=MIN(G$2:G$11),1,0)` makes the date green for the minimum deviation (I couldn't get it to work for the whole row - comments welcome).

There are other variations of this formula that could be useful.  Say you wanted a closer match to the Average Volume, then you could increase it's "weight" in the formula by multiplying the second term by a constant.

Edit: A statistician would probably insist on calculating the "sum of squares" of the individual deviations rather that the sum of the absolute values.

```
=((E2-B$1)/B$1)^2+((F2-B$2)/B$2)^2
```

Hope this helps, and best of luck.

Comment: Clever approach!